# How to configure multiple sitemaps with asp:menu control

Tags: web-config, sitemap, sitemapprovider, aspmenu

It's driving me nuts. I've searched and tried and searched and tried ... now I ask for your help!

I have an asp:menu control that uses a sitemap. Once the user is authenticated, I want to dynamically change the site map from code behind (c#). Here's the pertinent lines of code:

```
Site.Master:

<asp:Menu ID="aspMenu" runat="server" StaticDisplayLevels="1" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False">

<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="False"
StartFromCurrentNode="False" StartingNodeOffset="0" />

web.config:

  <siteMap defaultProvider="WebSitemap" >
    <providers>
      <add name="WebSitemap" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="Web.sitemap"/>
      <add name="MemberSiteMap" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="Member.sitemap"/>
    </providers>
  </siteMap>

Site.Master.cs:

    protected override void OnPreRender(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            SiteMapDataSource1.SiteMapProvider = "MemberSitemap";

        }
    }
```

After a successful build (VS 2010, 4.0 framework) I get the following error after a login:

Server Error in '/' Application.
The SiteMapProvider 'MemberSitemap' cannot be found.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks .... Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh, had the siteMap providers in the wrong section of web.config. I don't recommend web.config on sleep deprivation.